# How to make array construction?

Tags: php, arrays, hierarchy

i have a problem. I have two arrays and i need to put one into other like this:

```
array('1'=>1,'2'=>2,'3'=>array());
```

Can somebody advise how to solve it?

Comment: That very syntax will work.  Where are you stuck?

Comment: looks good, the problem is ?

Comment: I think that's the final array OP wants to produce..

Comment: @Babai if so whats the source?

Answer (score 1):

If your first array is

```
$first =  array('1'=>1,'2'=>2)
```

And the second is

```
$second =  array()
```

Then just add it in as

```
$first[] = $second
```

If the second is

```
$second[3] = array();
```

Then you want [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

```
$first = array_merge($first,$second)
```

There are all sorts of array functions on the left in that link, which come in very handy.

Comment: rather a large leap to say this is an 'answer'

Comment: @Dagon With the information the OP gave, it's as close as it can come.

Comment: that would be my point, perhaps wait and see what the op says to all the comments before even taking a guess